# How to import values from database into a OptionMenu Django Python

Tags: python, html, django, sqlite

I have a models page here.

```
 from django.db import models

class Trainee(models.Model):
TraineeID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
Course = models.CharField(max_length=20)
BatchNo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
DateofBirth = models.CharField(max_length=30)
ContactNo = models.CharField(max_length=20)
ContactAddress = models.CharField(max_length=80)
EmailAddress = models.EmailField()
class Meta():
    db_table = "Trainee"

class Course(models.Model):
CourseID = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
CourseName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
CourseDuration = models.CharField(max_length=30)
CourseCost = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class Meta():
    db_table = "Courses"
```

I made a html page where I can enter data and save `Trainee`. I want to make it so that `Course` will be a OptionMenu not a charfield that will have the options `<select>` only from the data saved in `Courses` table. So if there are saved data's like-Java, Python, C etc in `Courses` table then the option menu `Course` will only have these on it. And if they are deleted or new ones are added then the optionmenu will change accordingly. This is my html page where I can enter the data and save it:

```
{% extends "MyTestApp/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
{% load static %}                  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" />
<form method="post" action="/trainee/">
{%csrf_token%}

    <div class="container">

        <br/>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <h3> Enter Trainee Information </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> Name: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{form.Name}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="Course"> Course: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select name="Course" id="Course">
                        
                            <option value="{{courses.CourseName}}">{{courses.CourseName}}</option>
                        
                    </select>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> BatchNo: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{form.BatchNo}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label" for="DateofBirth"> Date Of Birth: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="date" name="DateofBirth" id="DateofBirth">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> ContactNo: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{form.ContactNo}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> ContactAddress: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{form.ContactAddress}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"> EmailAddress: </label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                {{form.EmailAddress}}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> Submit </button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I Hope I have made myself clear. Any help will be appreciated. I have been stuck at this for the past month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the issue here correctly you are looking for:

```
class Trainee(models.Model):
     ...
     course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
     ...
```

Read more about it here: [Django's ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey).
Btw. if you want to follow recommended PEP8 rules, and believe me you want to, model fields and variables should be snake_case (lower case).

Your form view in views.py might need to have `courses = Course.objects.all()` in it's context, depends on what you have in there.

views.py:

```
SomeView(AnyView):
    ...
    extra_context = {'courses': Course.objects.all()}
    ...
```

Then html form template:

```
...
<select name="course" id="id_course">

    {% for course in courses %}               
        <option value="{{ course.id }}">{{ course.course_name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>
...
```

It is usually better to pass value of `object.id` instead of `object.name`. Names should be for humans, ids for our algorithms.

Comment: a bit late to comment but how do you import data through ForeignKey. I know of ForeignKey from the start but it only has integer values so I thought it won't be useful. I have tried {%course in courses%} but it does not work. With "courses = Course.objects.all()" on views.py

Comment: I have edited the post with the basic way to add simple extra content in views.py that you can use in your template :)

Comment: Thank you very much man. I was stuck with this for so long. Finally able to solve it. The problem I was having was not adding {'courses': courses} context. For which" courses = Course.objects.all()" did not work. I did know that I had to add this context but did not know that I could add two context to one template. You answer helped to to solve this. Thank again.

Comment: You are welcome! For more complex content you can define funtion `get_context_data`, you can read about that in the Django's docs. If my answer was satysfying, please mark it as valid answer. :)